# Preencher um campo de parâmetro no Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, parâmetros, crystal-reports

Tenho um relatório do Crystal Reports onde devo passar parâmetros para a pesquisa, no entanto um destes parâmetros deve vir preenchido com um valor default que nada mais é que um campo do tipo `memo` de uma *view* do banco de dados. Este campo deve permitir que o usuário o edite para que este resultado seja inserido no relatório. Na prática tentei a seguinte sintaxe:

`Campo de parâmetro := Tabela.Campo`

Já percebi que este código não funciona no Crystal.

Comment: Não seria melhor uma formula !? Recebendo o valor do parametro !?

Comment: Motta, obrigado pelo retorno. O problema de ser uma fórmula é que neste caso eu não tenho como editar o que está escrito. Entendo que a fórmula, recebe o valor do parâmetro que foi preencido, no meu caso, este parâmetro deve vir preenchido e aberto para alteração e este resultado é que irá para o relatório. Espero ter conseguido me fazer entender.

Comment: Não entendi o problema , se o usuárioa passar "XPTO" no paramentro isto pode sair no relatório , mas se quer editar o relatório , é isto ? Não sei se entendi o problema.

Comment: Motta mais uma vez obrigado por responder. Imagina o seguinte, tenho uma tabela chamada `Insumos` esta tabela contém os dados que são usados em uma ordem de produção. Quando gero um relatório a tela de parâmetros abre com os campos em branco, pois, espera-se que eu coloque parâmetros lá para gerar o relatório. No meu caso, preciso que um dos campos de parâmetro já venha preenchido com a informação de um campo da tabela, este parâmetro deve permitir que eu o edite, para ai sim, a informação editada ser lançada no relatório. Espero que agora eu tenha conseguido ser mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

Isto não é feito no CR e sim na camada de interface (quando for o caso) , nela antes se pode montar um "form" e nele se faz pesquisas no BD para a montagem dos parâmetro, consultas a tabelas de tipagem , cidades , UFs , clientes etc.

Não pode ser feito no CR pois não haveria uma Fonte de Dados para isto , no CR o máximo que pode ser feito e definir um "default" no parâmetro.

Como é sua camada de interface ?

Comment: Bom dia Motta, mais uma vez, fico honrado com os comentários. Minha camada de interface com o usuário é o SAP B1. Deixa eu perguntar:Existe alguma forma de inserir uma consulta SQL no campo valor padrão da tela de configuração do parâmetro. Isso já seria o suficiente, pois, como uso uma view que já traz os dados formatados do banco, os dados já seriam inseridos no valor padrão da forma que preciso.

Comment: Em SAP nâo sei mas no ERP que uso o (Microsiga TOTVS) se pode criar um "PERGUNTE (SX1)" que é uma pergunta padrão interface com usuário , neste "pergunte" se pode sugerir valores , este "PERGUNTE" no fim é passado por parametro para um relatório Crystal Reports , o CR deve ter com certeza uma interface assim com o SAP pois são a mesma corporação agora.